# Unity monodevelop, if activate gameobject run script

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I will actually keep this short.I butchered this piece of code. I can't find the solutions.

My code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Linkbutton : MonoBehaviour{ 

    void Update()
    {   
        if (GameObject.activeSelf) 
         public void LinkFunc();

            {
            Application.OpenURL ("https://stolpersteinecoevorden.jimdo.com/stolpersteine/"); running = false; 

        }
                }
    }
```

The errors I'm having

[image]

I have been trying stuff for hours without a solution in view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zP91O. These are all my errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Linkbutton : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool running = true;

    void Update()
    {   
        if (this.gameObject.activeSelf) 
            LinkFunc();
    }

    public void LinkFunc()
    {


Application.OpenURL("https://stolpersteinecoevorden.jimdo.com/stolpersteine/");
        running = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It solved the grammar but now I have a new problem. running does not exist in current context.

Comment: You need to declare the running variable in your script, i edited my answer

Comment: Edited again :)

Comment: Holy shit  I can't believe you are still helping me out of my shithole. 

https://imgur.com/a/yxjXb
This is returning two errors. But I am pretty sure I made everything public.

Comment: @yommi you are not addressing an *instance* of linkbutton, you are trying to call a static method or property, which i do not think is your intention